# SPDY on Glassfish Application Server

Tags: jakarta-ee, web-applications, glassfish, spdy

I'm wondering if a Java App Server like Glassfish supports / will support [SPDY](http://dev.chromium.org/spdy/) and how this fits into the Java EE specs (and if some code changes would be required for full effect). At the moment there doesn't even exist a ticket for that (Glassfish Jira)? Why not? Does nobody care or need it?

I know that SPDY works with Jetty (so I could use it for some applications but not Java EE), there's mod_spdy for Apache and F5 load balancers do it. CDN Akamai supports it as well. The "missing link" seems to be the App Server?

I appreciate any hints.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to this pretty new [Issue on java.net](http://java.net/jira/browse/GLASSFISH-19393) SPDY support will be implemented in Glassfish 4 via GRIZZLY.

The [Roadmap](https://wikis.oracle.com/display/GlassFish/PlanForGlassFish4.0) states, that Glassfish 4.0 will be released somewhere in second half of 2013.

Comment: Thanks for updating me about this!